# Not able to log in to server

Tags: login

I have an Ubuntu server that was working fine last night, but today when I go to log in it says "permission denied". I am putting in the same username and password that I have always used.

I don't know how to make contact with the server.

How do I get access to it again?

I'm using a virtual Ubuntu server hosted by Coreweave and here's the prompt I get:

[image: Login prompt]

Comment: Check keyboard (keymap, capslock). How are you logging in? Via console, SSH?

Comment: Both via SSH and through the console directly. Keyboard is normal. I was recently playing around with ssh authentication.

Comment: If you know the password for `root`, login with that and reset your user password with `passwd your_username`. Otherwise, see suggested dupe to reset `root` pw.

Comment: @Panki I'm just a bit confused by the instructions there. What's a grub prompt? This is what shows up when I go to log in: https://imgur.com/a/oToI3Ks I'm using a cloud-hosted virtual ubuntu server

Comment: `grub` is your bootloader, you will need to force a reboot.